# How to create a clickable block?

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I have a view in Drupal 7 that displays 4 user field of the currently logged-in user. I rewrote the output to the following code:

```
<div>[field-1]</div>
<div>[field-2]</div>
<div>[field-3]</div>
<div>[field-4]</div>
```

I can add some CSS classes to the fields to let everything look a little bit better, but I'm stuck at a certain point: I'd like to add a link to the block that redirects the user to his/her profile page (the url is `user/[uid]`). To be completely clear, I'd like the *whole* block to function as some kind of "button" (just like the "button" in the top menu of this website), so I don't want the seperate fields to be linked to the profile page (I know how to do that anyway).

Can this be achieved with CSS and/or HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the 'div' in an 'a' element:

```
<a href="/user/id"><div>[field...]</div></a>
```

**Edit**: This will make all the text appear as a link, so might want to add some CSS. Example:

*HTML*:

```
<a class="link-box" href="/user/id"><div>[field...]</div></a>
```

*CSS*:

```
.link-box {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that makes the whole block clickable! Indeed, you immediately countered my next question. I'll try to customize it a bit with CSS.

Comment: @Jeroen The comment code got messed up after the edit somehow... fixed it for you. Glad to be of help :)

Comment: That works absolutely perfect. Thanks a lot! I couldn't imagine that it was that easy. ;)